# Print some of values from a .txt file using with row and column

Tags: python, txt

**MISSION: print some values(characters) from record.txt (utf-8).**

**PROBLEM:** i tried to get row 1-10 and column 1-3 it print row 1-10 but all of columns.

here is my print below spoiler. there should be 10x3 = 30 character

**HINT:** if i use different start_column variable (except "1" ) print is blank

> Tarih      Saat      Enlem(N)  Boylam(E) Derinlik(km)  MD   ML   Mw    Yer                                             Çözüm Niteliği
>
>  ---------- --------  --------  -------   ----------    ------------    --------------                                  --------------
>
>  2023.06.06 04:36:55  39.3747   41.0837        5.0      -.-  1.8  -.-   MOLLASAKIR-KARLIOVA (BINGOL)                      İlksel
>
>  2023.06.06 04:35:03  38.5848   37.5908        5.1      -.-  1.2  -.-   IRMAKLI-DARENDE (MALATYA)                         İlksel
>
>  2023.06.06 04:32:37  37.8855   36.2268        5.0      -.-  2.2  -.-   AKSAAGAC-SAIMBEYLI (ADANA)                        İlksel
>
>  2023.06.06 04:31:46  38.3480   38.8358        3.8      -.-  2.0  -.-   AKUSAGI-KALE (MALATYA)                            İlksel
>
>  2023.06.06 04:27:29  36.2065   30.1668       14.9      -.-  2.0  -.-   FINIKE ACIKLARI-ANTALYA (AKDENIZ)                 İlksel
>
>  2023.06.06 04:24:12  38.0925   37.4403        9.6      -.-  1.5  -.-   SUNNETKOY-ELBISTAN (KAHRAMANMARAS)                İlksel
>
>  2023.06.06 04:11:34  38.4632   37.5183        9.3      -.-  1.4  -.-   YENICE-DARENDE (MALATYA)                          İlksel
>
>  2023.06.06 04:02:02  38.3290   37.7035        7.9      -.-  1.7  -.-   BEKIRUSAGI-AKCADAG (MALATYA)                      İlksel
>
>  2023.06.06 04:01:15  39.1650   40.2747        5.2      -.-  1.7  -.-   SARIHAN-KARAKOCAN (ELAZIG)                        İlksel

```
def get_value_from_file(file_path, start_row, end_row, start_column, end_column):
    with open(file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        lines = file.readlines()

    selected_lines = lines[start_row-1:end_row]

    values = []
    for line in selected_lines:
        row_values = line.strip().split("\t")
        selected_values = row_values[start_column-1:end_column]
        values.extend(selected_values)

    return values

file_path = "record.txt"
start_row = 1
end_row = 10
start_column = 1
end_column = 3

result = get_value_from_file(file_path, start_row, end_row, start_column, end_column)
print(result)
```

**INFO:** Python 3.11.3

VSCode

[record.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZF_cGGwnwqai6CLe-1C9cWS-X8qQVhq_/view?usp=sharing)

Code generated by ChatGPT

**print should look like this**

tar

---

202

202

202

202

202

202

202

Comment: You can replace `2023.` with `\n2023.` in text file and then try loading this into `pandas` dataframe.

Comment: not working. \n is working. that rows doesn't exist in print but still print all of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is that you are blindly using code generated by ChatGPT.

The first part of the problem is caused by the fact that you are splitting your line based on the presence of tabs (`row_values = line.strip().split("\t")`), however, your text file does not contain any tabs, meaning it is not actually split.

The next part is due to the fact that you are `extend`ing your output list rather than `append`ing to it. This will cause all of the columns which you have nicely separated by rows to be placed on the same level, so that you lose the structure of your data. This makes coherently printing an output much more difficult.

Finally, in order to display things in the format you desire, you need to be a bit more specific with your `print`. Typically, you want to print each line on a new line. This will require either some formatting, or a loop.

I'm a bit confused by what you want to achieve. Your question seems to indeicate that all you want to do is print the characters between `start_column` and `end_column`, so the simplest way to do that would be something along the lines of :

```py
def get_slice_from_file(file_path, start_row, end_row, start_column, end_column):
    with open(file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        lines = file.readlines()

    # take only the lines which interest us
    selected_lines = lines[start_row-1:end_row]

    # from each line, take only the characters which interest us, and
    # place them in a list
    selected_characters = []
    for line in selected_lines:
        selected_characters.append(line[start_column-1:end_column])

    # BONUS: all this can be shortened using list comprehension
    # selected_characters = [line[start_column-1:end_column]
    #                        for line in lines[start_row-1:end_row]]

    return selected_characters

result = get_slice_from_file(file_path, start_row, end_row, start_column, end_column)

# print
for result_line in result:
    print(result_line)

# BONUS: this can again be simplified using the "splat" (*) operator and the `sep` (separator) keyword
# print(*result, sep="\n")
```